PostgreSQL: count unique values from multiple columns
Lets have a table with two columns [col1, col2] with some values. values in col1 and col2 can be repeated. I would like to get number of unique values from both columns.
select
   count(distinct col1) as col1_unique,
   count(distinct col2) as col2_unique,
   count(distinct (col1, col2)) as total_unique
from myTable

that returns total_unique as combination of col1, col2 which is always bigger then a sum of col1_unique and col2_unique
as example:
table with rows:
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 2
2 2

should return col1_unique as 2, col2_unique as 3 and total_unique 3
I can add a select for col1 and col2 and then distinct values from the select, but is there better (nicer) way to solve the task?

You could union the columns and treat them as one set, if that's what you mean. select count(distinct val) from (select col1 as val from mytable union select col2 from mytable)_; Have you got any indexes set up on these?

@Zegarek thank you for the idea! yes, it is about union of two columns. Yes, there is index for the table. Can I count unique values for both columns and each of the column in one request?

A tagged union of the column values and then conditional aggregation would look and read very well. Not necessarily very efficient though.
select count(distinct col) filter (where tag = 1),
       count(distinct col) filter (where tag = 2),
       count(distinct col)
from (
  select col1 as col, 1 as tag from the_table
  union all
  select col2, 2 from the_table
) t;

Demo

much appreciate for details! Yes, it works!
